# Basic hit counter also affecting images?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hitcounter

I have recently added a hit counter to my page to see what domains people are coming from. Since I have two domains that point to the same IP, which I recently have acquired.

All requests go to my index.php file, which determines how to display the page. I have it set up like so, because I plan on having multiple pages, like user pages or forum posts, and can't have a multitude of folders. 
.htaccess is set up like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

At the start of my index.php I have:

```
(Bit of code that determines the domain used)
$conn = connectDB();
$result = $conn->query('UPDATE hitCounter SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE domain = "'.$domain.'"');
$conn->close();
```

However, images count as a hit. If I were to go to domain.com/img/img.png 
It would count as a hit. How can I stop it from doing this? (I have a bit of javascript, that makes particles to 'fall' from the top. This caused the number of hits go up by 1000 in an hour)

Comment: where you determine which domain is being asked for, check to see if an image is being requested, and if one isn't then log it otherwise skip logging

Comment: Are your images physical files or loaded via index.php?

Comment: Are you sure the images are counting as a hit?  Perhaps temporarily try to log the request URI and/or double check your server logs.  It could be a request for something that isn't there: a favicon perhaps.  How do you deal with 404s?

Comment: just install goggle analytics or analyse the access log

Comment: @ivanivan I've included it to not count hits, if the REQUEST_URI has 'img' yet it still counts domain.com/img/img.png as a hit

Comment: @Progrock You're correct. It was checking for a favicon... Right now, dealing with 404s through index.php. So would count that as a hit. 
Do you know why the browser searches for a favicon at domain.com/favicon.ico instead of the icon I have in the <link rel="icon"> for my index page? Should I keep a favicon in the root folder just to deal with this?

Comment: Might be worth posting as another problem/question.  With browser name/s and versions. :)